# count of Daily Uploads by Users

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I get Count of Daily uploads by users.

Let's say. Few users uploads data like below

```
UserID|Username|    UploadedOn       |Status

768   |K9283   |01-02-2017 11:38:42 AM|Success
768   |K9283   |08-02-2017 12:48:22 AM|Success
761   |K9287   |01-02-2017 11:58:02 AM|Success
768   |K9283   |02-02-2017 09:50:22 AM|Success
764   |K9289   |01-02-2017 10:40:32 AM|Success
769   |K9189   |05-02-2017 10:40:32 AM|Success
```

I am looking for a query which I will get results for the date greater than 05-Feb-2017

Results should be like:

```
userID|Count

768|1

769|1
```

is it possible with SQL query.

**edit:** The database is Oracle, I am testing the queries on SQL Navigator 6.5

Comment: Why are you storing your dates as text?  We can't even give you a workaround right now because you also didn't tag with your database.

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What's table name?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That timestamp format seems to be product specific. Or is it varchar???

Comment: @saeed data_summary is the table Name.

Comment: @jarlh  It is a Oracle Database, the server date format is UTC.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is a oracle Database.

Comment: Dose SQL code helps?
Right now I have SQL installed on my system.

Comment: @saeed yes. I guess.

Comment: So, what is the **data type** of `UploadedOn`? Is it `date` or `varchar2`? (Best not to guess; find out **for sure**). Then: You said you want count of "daily" uploads, but then you want uploads "greater than" February 5. Judging by the results, you want "greater than **or equal to**" February 5. What will be February 5 in your application - an input date, supplied by the user? And you don't want a "daily count", just a "total count" - also judging by the results. Right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty simple to me:

```
select userId, count(*) records
from yourTable
where uploadedOn >= to_date(2017-02-05, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
group by userID
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this code works on Oracle but this one works fine in SQL Server.
Anyway I think this helps ;)

```
SELECT     UserID, COUNT(UserID) AS UserCount
FROM         myTable
GROUP BY UserID, Status, UploadedOn
HAVING      (Status = 1) AND (UploadedOn > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-02-05 00:00:00', 102))
```

[image]